# using autocomplete search that return two properties of two different tables

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I was working with autocomplete search of jquery-ui and I added a property of other object using the include, I hope be useful

HTML:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<input type="text" id="tags" />
```

json in view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tag = $("#tags").val();
    console.log(tag);
    $('#tags').autocomplete(
        {
            source: '@Url.Action("TagSearch", "Quote")'
        });

});


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

controller actionResult:

```
public ActionResult TagSearch(string term)
    {
        string[] quotes = context.Quotes.Include(c => c.Model).Select(c =>    c.Number + "  " + "Model" + " " + c.Model.Number ).ToArray();
        return this.Json(quotes.Where(t => t.StartsWith(term)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  This is a Q&A site.  It seems like you're showing the Q&A, in which case you need to just provide the Q here, and then provide the A below.  But I don't know if you want to do that as someone new to SO.

Comment: yep I'm new here, and want share this because I had been looking for and I haven't found anything about it, so when I solved it, I wanted share it.

Comment: Then you'll need to separate this into a question here ("How do I...?") and an answer below.  If you don't, this could get closed.